# Add a custom select field with collection times in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, custom-fields

I have created a custom checkout field for collection times on my website (see image attached)

This is my current code:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'njengah_add_select_checkout_field');
function njengah_add_select_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
    woocommerce_form_field( 'daypart', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array( 'njengah-drop' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Collection Time' ),
        'required'      => true,   
        'options'       => array(
            'blank'   => __( 'Select a collection time', 'njengah' ),
            '5:00_PM' => __( '5:00 PM', 'njengah' ),
            '5:30_PM' => __( '5:30 PM', 'njengah' ),
            '6:00_PM' => __( '6:00 PM', 'njengah' ),
            '6:30_PM' => __( '6:30 PM', 'njengah' ),
            '7:00_PM' => __( '7:00 PM', 'njengah' ),
            '7:30_PM' => __( '7:30 PM', 'njengah' ),
            '8:00_PM' => __( '8:00 PM', 'njengah' )
        )
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'daypart' ));
}
```

[image: example]

---

However, the intention is to hide collection times when time has passed

E.G. - If its 6pm hide: 5:00 PM and 5:30 PM

Any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WordPress [current_time()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_time/) function which retrieves the current time based on specified type.

From that point on you can further customize your code to suit your needs, so you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_before_order_notes( $checkout ) {
    // Open and close time
    $start_time = strtotime( '9:00 AM' );
    $stop_time = strtotime( '1:00 PM' );

    /* END SETTINGS */
    
    // Current time
    $current_time = current_time( 'timestamp' );
    
    // Initialize
    $remaining_times = array();
    $required = true;
    
    // Closed
    if( $current_time > $stop_time || $current_time <= $start_time ) {
        // Default value
        $default[''] = __( 'Closed', 'woocommerce');
        
        // False
        $required = false;
    } else {    
        // Default value
        $default[''] = __( 'Select a collection time', 'woocommerce');
        
        // Determine first value
        $first_value = strtotime( date( 'g:i A', ceil( $current_time / 1800 ) * 1800 ) );
        
        // Add a new option every 30 minutes
        while( $first_value <= $stop_time && $first_value >= $start_time ) {
            $value = date( 'g:i A', $first_value );
            $remaining_times[$value] = $value;
            
            // Add 30 minutes
            $first_value = strtotime( '+30 minutes', $first_value );
        }
    }
    
    // Options
    $options = array_merge( $default, $remaining_times );

    // Add field
    woocommerce_form_field( 'daypart', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array( 'njengah-drop' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Collection Time', 'woocommerce' ),
        'required'      => $required,  
        'options'       => $options,
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'daypart' ));
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'action_woocommerce_before_order_notes', 10, 1 );
```

E.G.

- Current time = 9:14 AM
- First value = 9:30 AM
- Last value = 1:00 PM (stop time)

[image: result_time]

---

---

**Additional question:** Suppose the start time is 5:00 PM and the stop time is 8:00 PM. How can I give the customers the opportunity to order from 12:00 PM, while the first slot is 5:00 PM?

Use the following code instead:

```php
function action_woocommerce_before_order_notes( $checkout ) {
    // Display time, open and close time
    $display_time = strtotime( '12:00 PM' );
    $start_time = strtotime( '5:00 PM' );
    $stop_time = strtotime( '8:00 PM' );

    // END SETTINGS
    
    // Current time
    $current_time = current_time( 'timestamp' );
    
    // Initialize
    $remaining_times = array();
    $required = true;
    
    // Closed
    if( $current_time > $stop_time || $current_time <= $display_time ) {
        // Default value
        $default[''] = __( 'Closed', 'woocommerce');
        
        // False
        $required = false;
    } else {    
        // Default value
        $default[''] = __( 'Select a collection time', 'woocommerce');
        
        // Determine first value
        $first_value = strtotime( date( 'g:i A', ceil( $current_time / 1800 ) * 1800 ) );
        
        // First value is less than start time
        if ( $first_value < $start_time ) {
            $first_value = $start_time;
        }
        
        // Add a new option every 30 minutes
        while( $first_value <= $stop_time && $first_value >= $start_time ) {
            $value = date( 'g:i A', $first_value );
            $remaining_times[$value] = $value;
            
            // Add 30 minutes
            $first_value = strtotime( '+30 minutes', $first_value );
        }
    }
    
    // Options
    $options = array_merge( $default, $remaining_times );

    // Add field
    woocommerce_form_field( 'daypart', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array( 'njengah-drop' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Collection Time', 'woocommerce' ),
        'required'      => $required,  
        'options'       => $options,
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'daypart' ));
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'action_woocommerce_before_order_notes', 10, 1 );
```

E.G.

- Current time = 12:05 PM
- First value = 5:00 PM
- Last value = 8:00 PM (stop time)

[image: result_time_extra]

---

Related: [Add a select field with time intervals based on opening, closing and breaks times in WooCommerce checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64941894/11987538)