# How to show checkout custom fields value in Woo Commerce order edit page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using [Add a custom select field with collection times in WooCommerce checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67889698/add-a-custom-select-field-with-collection-times-in-woocommerce-checkout) to create a collection dropdown

my question is how do I get my collection time to show up in the backend of woo
[image: collection time]

If I select 8 PM as the collection time, the collection time in the backend shows as number 7. Witch is the 7th option (8 PM)

```
function collection_time( $checkout ) {
    // Display time, open and close time
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
    $display_time = strtotime( '12:00 PM' );
    $start_time = strtotime( '5:00 PM' );
    $stop_time = strtotime( '8:00 PM' );

    // END SETTINGS
    
    // Current time
    $current_time = current_time( 'timestamp' );
    
    // Initialize
    $remaining_times = array();
    $required = true;
    
    // Closed
    if( $current_time > $stop_time || $current_time <= $display_time ) {
        // Default value
        $default[''] = __( 'Closed', 'woocommerce');
        
        // False
        $required = false;
    } else {    
        // Default value
        $default[''] = __( 'Select a collection time', 'woocommerce');
        
        // Determine first value
        $first_value = strtotime( date( 'g:i A', ceil( $current_time / 1800 ) * 1800 ) );
        
        // First value is less than start time
        if ( $first_value < $start_time ) {
            $first_value = $start_time;
        }
        
        // Add a new option every 30 minutes
        while( $first_value <= $stop_time && $first_value >= $start_time ) {
            $value = date( 'g:i A', $first_value );
            $remaining_times[$value] = $value;
            
            // Add 30 minutes
            $first_value = strtotime( '+30 minutes', $first_value );
        }
    }
    
    // Options
    $options = array_values( $default + $remaining_times );

    // Add field
    woocommerce_form_field( 'daypart', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array( 'njengah-drop' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Collection Time', 'woocommerce' ),
        'required'      => $required,  
        'options'       => $options,
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'daypart' ));
}

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'process_collection_time_field');
function process_collection_time_field() {
    if (isset($_POST['daypart']) && empty($_POST['daypart']) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please select a collection time' ), 'error' );
    }
}


//* Update the order meta with field value
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'select_checkout_field_update_order_meta');
function select_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
if ($_POST['daypart']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'daypart', esc_attr($_POST['daypart']));
}

//* Display field value on the order edition page

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'njengah_select_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function njengah_select_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
echo '<p><strong>'.__('Collection Time').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'daypart', true ) . '</p>';
}

//* Add selection field value to emails
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'njengah_select_order_meta_keys');
function njengah_select_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {
$keys['Daypart:'] = 'daypart';
return $keys;
}`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `array_merge()`. check below code.

`array_values()` values reset the keys of the array that's why you get 7 instead of 8:00 PM.

change this below line.

```
$options = array_values( $default + $remaining_times );
```

to

```
$options = array_merge( $default, $remaining_times );
```

Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Welcome... glad to be of help.